# how to seperate storing IP address for each click event in php

Tags: php, html

It is about this situation:

I have 2 photos and under each photo you can "like" or "dislike" the photo by voting. To prevent multiple times voting per user, i store the IP address of the user. So with the same IP a user can only vote once per photo.
My problem now is: if IP is already stored by clicking on Like under photo 1, he/she can not like or dislike photo2 anymore. And this should be possible.

This is the html code i have:

```
<!-- here is photo 1 with below the buttons-->
<button id="like-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="like">Like</button> 
<span id="like" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['like'];?></span> likes.
<br/><br/>

<button id="dislike-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="dislike">Dislike</button> 
<span id="dislike" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['dislike'];?>    </span> dislikes.
<br/><br/>

<!-- here is photo2 with below the buttons-->
<button id="like-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="like2">Like</button> 
<span id="like" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['like2'];?></span> likes.
<br/><br/>
```

And the php code:

```
// grab users IP address
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$UserIptxt = $ipAddress."||";
$all_ips = explode("||", file_get_contents("user_ip.txt"));
if ( ! in_array($ipAddress, $all_ips) ) {

  // put the ip address in .txt file
  file_put_contents("user_ip.txt", $UserIptxt, FILE_APPEND);


  $file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
  $fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
  $id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
  $lines = '';
  while(!feof($fh)){
    $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
    $item = trim($line[0]);
    $num = trim($line[1]);
    if(!empty($item)){
      if($item == $id){
        $num++; // increment count by 1
        echo $num;
        echo '<br />Thanks for voting';

      }
      $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
     }
  } 
  file_put_contents($file, $lines);
  fclose($fh);

}
// ip adres is already stored
else {
 echo '<br /><div class="alreadyvoted">You have already voted!</div>';
}
```

The file `counter.txt` looks like this:

```
like||117
dislike||184
like2||12
dislike2||18
```

How can i distinguish storing IP address for each photo?

Comment: ip!=user this approach is fundamentally flawed

Comment: ^ In addition to that, the line '*//put the ip address in .txt file*' send shudders down my spine with regards to security. Use something like cookies / sessions to track users, and use a database for storage instead of a .txt file :)

Comment: Yes, don't use IP addresses for this. Use something like a cookie/session, or web storage.

Comment: dont use cookies\session unless you have a user managment system

Comment: Oke. I can use a cookie instead of storing IP addresses. But then still remains the porblem of distinguish

Comment: do you have user management? because a cookie is pointless with out it, i could vote, delete cookie, vote again etc

Comment: no i do not have a user management. Everybody should have the possibilty to vote without logging in. Its for the customers of the webpage

Comment: you need one if you want to stop multiple votes, if its a low value system (no benefit to person voting) and you don care that much a cookie will stop the average person voting multiple times and be easier to run than logging and checking ip's

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, with this method each photo needs a unique ID you save with the Ip address. Maybe save it in the file in a form something like

```
127.0.0.0=photo1

127.0.0.0=photo2
```

Then explode each line

```
list ($ipAddr,$photoID) = explode ("#", $line);
```

Then compare the passed photoID and IP.

May want to look into possibly using a database however. This could be far easier creating entries and drawing this info out using the WHERE clause.